# rasterio and gdal DLL load fail in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, conda, gdal, rasterio

I have a conda environment with rasterio installed and a whole load of other libraries, including gdal.

When I do:

```
import rasterio
```

on jupyter notebook, it loads fine and I can utilise it's methods etc..

When I do exactly the same thing on PyCharm, with the same environment and interpreter, I can the following error:

```
from rasterio._base import gdal_version
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I'm struggling to understand why this is the case, as it loads fine in jupter notebook.

Comment: What PyCharm version do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same problem as you and has finished solving it.

First, You need to ensure that gdal version is still 2.x. If no, just remove it.

```sh
conda remove rasterio gdal -y
```

then reinstall gdal with specifying the installation version:

```sh
conda install rasterio gdal=2 -y
```

Then, you need add `GDAL_DATA` which containing a `gcs.csv` file to environment，
for me in Windows:

```sh
setx /m GDAL_DATA C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\python3\Library\share\gdal
```

reboot your computer, and import gdal before importing rasterio:

```py
In [1]: import rasterio
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-350e27267e59> in <module>
----> 1 import rasterio

~\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\python3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in <module>
     20             pass
     21
---> 22 from rasterio._base import gdal_version
     23 from rasterio.drivers import is_blacklisted
     24 from rasterio.dtypes import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: 找不到指定的模块。

In [2]: from osgeo import gdal

In [3]: import rasterio
```

Answer (score 0):

I just imported the `gdal` library before.

```
from osgeo import gdal

import rasterio
```

This worked for me.