# How to get Jupyter Notebook to link to another python installation?

Tags: python, installation, package, jupyter, rasterio

I am trying to use a specific package called `rasterio` in python which I have been unable to use. What I am specifically confused about is the disconnect I am seeing between Windows Command Prompt, Anaconda Prompt, and Jupyter Notebook, the platform I use for python.

I open Jupyter Notebook and run `import rasterio` and get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-350e27267e59> in <module>
----> 1 import rasterio

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py in <module>
     15 from pathlib import Path
     16 
---> 17 from rasterio._base import gdal_version
     18 from rasterio.drivers import driver_from_extension, is_blacklisted
     19 from rasterio.dtypes import (

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I then try to run in Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3) after running python: and get basically the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\MyName\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from rasterio._base import gdal_version
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

But then I try with Windows Command Prompt, running python and then import rasterio, and the package imports successfully.

And then I notice that running `python` on Anaconda Prompt shows:

```
Python 3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
```

And running `python_version()` in Jupyter Notebook produces:

```
'3.7.4'
```

And then I see running `python` in Windows Command Prompt shows:

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

And so it seems like python in Windows Command Prompt is just in a totally different space than what is being run on Jupyter Notebook and Anaconda Prompt. For some reason `rasterio` installed successfully with Python 3.9.5 but not with Python 3.7.4. And so while I have been struggling to get rasterio to install correctly, it looks like I already have installed it successfully. But my question is how can I get Jupyter Notebook to "talk" to my python version from Command Prompt so that it "understands" I already installed this package? I simply just want to use this package in Jupyter Notebook, but it just seems like Jupyter Notebook does not understand that it is already installed.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with the PATH environment setting. Did you install with pip when you installed rasterio? Install using conda from Anaconda Prompt.

Comment: Yes, when I used pip within Command Prompt to install rasterio, which let it install fine. However, installing rasterio via conda from Anaconda Prompt has turned into a lost cause almost. I detailed it in this post here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417733/unable-to-import-python-rasterio-package-even-though-it-is-installed?noredirect=1#comment680243_417733

Comment: Hmmm, try the following. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596662/rasterio-and-gdal-dll-load-fail-in-pycharm